# Close notification on rejected migrations doesn't make much sense

Tags: feature-request, migration, on-hold, migration-rejection

When a migrated question is closed, it also gets automatically locked, which means it can't be voted on, commented on or edited. That's all great, but:

[image]

First of all, there's nothing "on hold" about a locked question. The whole "this is temporary" feeling of the (supposedly) friendlier verbiage doesn't make much sense for a question that was send back where it came from, leaving nothing behind but a locked stub.

Then, of course, there's the encouragement to edit the question or leave a comment, neither of which is possible. To be fair, above the migration notice there's a low contrast (and thus extremely easy to miss) message telling us that "comments [are] disabled on deleted / locked posts / reviews" and the edit link is disabled.

I think it would make a bit more sense to:

- Display rejected migrations as "closed" from day one. There's nothing "on hold" about them, and the wording is more confusing than helpful.
- Remove that last sentence of the close notification completely (or replace it with a sentence telling us the question is locked).

And a bonus bug report:

If you try to upvote a comment on a rejected migration, it fails with a "This comment is not eligible for voting or flagging" message. However, I was able to flag [this comment](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/14206/how-do-i-prevent-myself-from-leaning-too-close-to-the-monitor#comment34205_14206). No idea if my flag actually went through or not, but from my end it looks like it did (even the flag icon is gone on refresh).

Comment: Your flag did indeed go through.

Comment: @Jim Thanks, and sorry for the bs flag. I was going to flag a comment on Politics to check this, but then I remembered a comment flag from a mod would just kill the comment.